# How to use devise parent_controller for devise inherited controller but skip for ActiveAdmin devise controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am developing Api based application, site.com (Client App), api.site.com (Server App)

In my api.site.com, there are passwords, confirmations controller, which are inherited from the Devise controllers. By default Devise parent controller is Application controller, but Devise inherited controllers need to pass through ApiBaseController api_authentication action. So, Devise.rb has following configuration:

```
config.parent_controller = 'ApiBaseController'
```

Api authentication is working fine now.

ApiBaseController sample code:

```
class ApiBaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :api_authentication

  def api_authentication
    api_key = request.headers['Api-Key']
    @app = Application.find_by_api_key(api_key) if api_key
    unless @app
     return render json: { errors: { message: 'Something went wrong, contact admin', code: '1000' } }
    end
  end
end
```

Now i am using ActiveAdmin, after installing ActiveAdmin i tried to open http://localhost:3000/admin/login on browser, I saw following error response on browser instead of active admin login page:

`{"errors":{"message":"Something went wrong, contact admin","code":1000}}`

I checked the issue, and i realized that `active_admin/devise/sessions` controller also passed through ApiBaseController. This is because we had set our parent controller to ApiBaseController (`config.parent_controller = 'ApiBaseController'`). I removed the code and ActiveAdmin worked fine.

But passwords, confirmations controller did not passed through the ApiBaseController api_authentication() since i removed the Devise configuration (`config.parent_controller = 'ApiBaseController'`).

So if you guys have understood the problem, please let me know the solution.

In summary, i need all the api Devise inherited controllers need to pass through ApiBaseController for api_authentication() check and ActiveAdmin Devise controllers do not need to pass through ApiBaseController.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching the way to add the condition inside the Devise parent_controller, but i did not get any solution for Devise. But, i solved it by adding some code.

```
class ApiBaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :api_authentication

  def api_authentication
   return true if params[:controller].include?("active_admin/devise/")
    api_key = request.headers['Api-Key']
    @app = Application.find_by_api_key(api_key) if api_key
    unless @app
     return render json: { errors: { message: 'Something went wrong, contact admin', code: '1000' } }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You just write you api authentication logic in `application_controller.rb` and use `before_filter` in your password controller or where ever you want.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

 private

 def api_authentication
    api_key = request.headers['Api-Key']
    @app = Application.find_by_api_key(api_key) if api_key
    unless @app
      return render json: { errors: { message: 'Something went wrong, contact admin', code: '1000' } }
    end
  end
 end
```

and use `before_filter :api_authentication` in your controller

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  before_filter :api_authentication

  .......
end
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want any code inside ApplicationController, we already have ApiBaseController

Comment: then you can use `before_action :api_authentication, if: :json_request?` in your api base controller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will try this. BTW, i resolved it, i was expecting solution from Devise, because i may have many parents like ApiBaseController in future.